# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (66256, 58)

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I am new at this so if anyone can explain the error it would help me alot

code:

```
train_image, test_image, train_label, test_label = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.30,random_state=42)#splits data, 30% for test and 70% for train 
train_image = train_image.reshape(train_image.shape[0],32,32,3)
test_image = test_image.reshape(test_image.shape[0],32,32,3)
train_label = to_categorical(train_label, num_classes=len(data['Class']))
test_label = to_categorical(test_label, num_classes=len(data['Class']))

model = Sequential()
conv_01 = Conv2D(filters = 32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,3))
model.add(conv_01)
conv_02 = Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu')
model.add(conv_02)
pool = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2),strides = (2,2), padding = 'same')
model.add(pool)
conv_11 = Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu')
model.add(conv_11)
pool_2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2),padding='same')
model.add(pool_2)
drop = Dropout(0.3)
model.add(drop)
conv_out = Conv2D(filters = 3,kernel_size=(1,1),activation='softmax')
model.add(conv_out)
model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_image,train_label,epochs=10,verbose = 1,validation_data=(test_image,test_label))
tes_loss,test_acc = model.evaluate(test_image,test_label)
prediction = model.predict(test_image)
```

train_image.shape :(66256, 32, 32, 3)

test_image.shape : (28396, 32, 32, 3)

train_label.shape : (66256, 58)

test_label.shape : (28396, 58)

error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processing.py", line 59, in <module>
    model.fit(train_image,train_label,epochs=10,verbose = 1,validation_data=(test_image,test_label))
  File "/home/mihir/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1278, in fit
    validation_split=validation_split)
  File "/home/mihir/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 917, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/mihir/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 182, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (66256, 58)
```

Comment: why are you using conv2d layer as output layer? why not dense?

Comment: @Mitiku Trying build a fully convolution network

Comment: Fully convolution networks with convolutional last layer are usually used for image segmentation. In this case the target also should be image. In your case the targets don't seem image data(e.g train_label shape is (66256, 58)). I recommend using Dense layer.

Comment: @Mitiku can you tell me why is it taking the target as train label?

Comment: What I mean when I say target is, the output of the network, this values are feed to the model as second argument of model.fit method

Answer (score 1):

In the context of classification, which seems is the task you are trying to perform, usually there are multiple conv + pooling layers at the beginning and then they are followed by one or a few dense layers (i.e. fully connected layer, usually abbreviated as "fc"). One more thing that you need to consider is that you should use a `Flatten` layer right before the first Dense layer to flatten the output of last convolution layer.

Here is your code after considering the points above:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2),strides = (2,2), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters =128,kernel_size=(1,1),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(58, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

Here is the model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 12, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 6, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 6, 6, 128)         8320      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 3, 3, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 1152)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                73792     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 58)                3770      
=================================================================
Total params: 142,202
Trainable params: 142,202
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

​